# How to Disable or Stop Angular BlockUI on particular request

Tags: angularjs, blockui

I have turned on automaticly BlockUI show on any request, but i need to turn off on a particular request. I need something like this.

```
$scope.getTags = function ($query) {
            blockUI.notShow();
            return blogService.getTags($query)
        };
```

Answer (score 8):

I try something and work.

**1) Stop Autoblock**

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "blockUIConfig", function ($routeProvider, blockUIConfig) {
    blockUIConfig.autoBlock = false;
}]);
```

**2) Create an Interceptor**

```
app.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptorService');
}]);
app.factory('myInterceptorService', ['$q', '$injector','blockUI',
    function ($q, $injector, blockUI) {

        var myInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

        myInterceptorServiceFactory.request = function (config) {
            if (blockUI.noOpen == null) {
            blockUI.stop();
        } else {
            blockUI.noOpen = null;
        }
            return config;
        }
        myInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = function (rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
        myInterceptorServiceFactory.response = function (response) {
            if (blockUI.noOpen == null) {
            blockUI.stop();
        } else {
            blockUI.noOpen = null;
        }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }

        return myInterceptorServiceFactory;
    }
]);
```

**3) Alert in Controller**

```
$scope.getTags = function ($query) {
            blockUI.noOpen = true;
            return blogService.getTags($query)
        };
```

Comment: I think you've made a typo: the first `if (blockUI.noOpen == null)` shouldn't be `if (blockUI.noOpen == true)`?

Answer (score 2):

with McNull AngularJS Block UI Module... you can filter out a particular request using blockUIConfig.requestFilter function...

```
angular.module('yourAppModule').config(["blockUIConfig", function (blockUIConfig) {
    blockUIConfig.requestFilter = function (config) {
    //Perform a global, case-insensitive search on the request url for 'noblockui' ...
    if (config.url.match(/noblockui/gi)) {
        return false; // ... don't block it.
    }
};}]);
```

on the particular request just add the following to the url...

```
url = backendAddress + "/?noblockui";
return $http.get(url);
```